# Make the div goes under another

Tags: wordpress, tabs

I have to style the tab slider in Wordpress, so the tab navigation div happens to be on top and the the content is under, I want to switch them but I can't
, the tab-content has position: relative already because of its content.

Here I try

```
  css
  .wrapper {
        position: relative; 
   }
  .tab-nav {
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
   }
```

but tab-nav goes down but stick into the tab-content. so this way does not work.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="tab-nav">
     </div>
     <div class="tab-content">
     </div>
 </div>
```

I want to use css to make the tab-nav is under the tab-content. its be better if we dont use "position"

Answer (score 1):

In `.tab-nav` set `z-index=-1;` and then `left` / `right` and `top` / `bottom` attributes to place it where you want.

Comment: Hi is there another way not to use position?  because the  nav-content has position : relative at first so its really confusing me.

Comment: Do you want contents to overlap or side-by-side or stacked? Could you give a JSFiddle link or an image link of what you're trying to do?